# Can't use/find Amazon SQS sendMessageBatch()

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

According to [their docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-sqs-messages.html) and [example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/java/example_code/sqs/src/main/java/aws/example/sqs/SendReceiveMessages.java), I should be able to use my SQS client to sendMessageBatch(). However, all I have at my disposal is sqs.sendMessage(sendMessageRequest).

I'm setting up as follows:

```
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    AmazonSQS sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(awsCreds);
```

and then trying to call sqs.sendMessageBatch(), but that method is not part of the AmazonSQS interface, despite their documentation. Have they simple changed it without updating their docs? If so, does anyone know of a way to batch messages?

I'm using 'aws-java-sdk-sqs', version: '1.11.274'

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/1.11.274/aws-java-sdk-sqs/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQS.java#L971) it certainly appears to be there. What makes you think that it isn't (hint: show the code that you're trying to use, along with the compiler error; what you've shown doesn't indicate anything).

Comment: @kdgregory I get this:
Error:(31, 20) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method sendMessageBatch(com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SendMessageBatchRequest)
  location: variable sqs of type com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. Just in case the downloaded SDK artifact did not match the code on Github, I created a test program using version 1.1.274, and verified that the method does indeed exist. My best advice is that you start a new project with a single class that consists of just two lines: one that initializes an `AmazonSQS` variable to null, and one that attempts to call that method. This will either demonstrate to you that the method exists, or give a complete example (including buildfile) that you can add to this question (_not_ as a comment).

Comment: The most likely cause is that you have a problem with your build classpath.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is something wrong with my build classpath.
In addition to 1.1.274, I've also go aws-java-sdk-1.0.002.jar and it's using the latter for some reason. Thanks, though - at least I now know what the root of the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem:

I pulled in both aws-java-sdk and aws-java-sdk-sqs using Gradle.
Seems aws-java-sdk also contains an AmazonSQS interface. My code was using this rather than aws-java-sdk-sqs's version.

The thing is, I pulled in different versions of aws-java-sdk and aws-java-sdk-sdk. All I did was remove the aws-java-sdk dependency as I didn't actually need it.